# Django | For some error, different url show same template

Tags: django

I have problems with urls. For example "questions/" shows "def question_list" function well, but "subjects/" url doesn´t show "def subject_list" fucntion. For some reason "subject/" url also show question_list. why?

project>**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('questions/', include('questions.urls')),
path('subjects/', include('questions.urls')),
]
```

APPquestions>**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        views.question_list,
        name='questions',
    ),
    path('subjects/',
        views.subject_list,
        name='subjects',
    ),
]
```

APPquestions>**views.py**

```
def question_list(request):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter().order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(preguntas,1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    preguntas = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'questions/questions.html', {'preguntas': preguntas})

def subject_list(request):
    categorias = Categoria.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'questions/subjects.html', {'categorias': categorias})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening simply because the two paths are referring to the same view

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('questions/', include('questions.urls')), # This one
    path('subjects/', include('questions.urls')),  # And this one
]
```

You are including the same `urls.py` file in the two paths
and that file has the following sub-paths

- `/`         ---> root of the sub-path
- `subjects/` ---> which is subjects sub-path

which means you now have 4 urls

1. `/questions/` ---> this will route you to `question_list` view
2. `/questions/subjects/` ---> this will route you to `subject_list` view
3. `/subjects/` ----> this will route you to `question_list` view
4. `/subjects/subjects/` ---> this will route you to `subject_list` view

You will always fall back to the root sub-path of `questions/urls.py`

It is either you use `/questions/subjects/` url to get to the right view

or

re-structure you app's routes urls.

Comment: thanks! with /questions/subjects/ is ok! thanks Radwan Abu-Odeh!